# Mostrar valores negativos de una tabla JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, table

Tengo una tabla que lleno con una consulta mysql y un botón que apunta a una función para realizar un calculo, multiplica el valor que hay en un `<input>` por cada valor de la columna "cantidad" y lo resta a cada valor que hay en la columna "stock actual". El resultado lo coloca en la columna "stock restante".

Necesito mostrar un mensaje en la función si alguno de los valores del resultado es negativo. Adjunto la imagen de la tabla y el código del problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function asignar() {
    var dato1 =  document.getElementById("canti").value;
    if(dato1.trim().length == 0 ){
     alertify.alert("Atención","Por favor ingrese datos para cantidad");
     return false;
    }
    else{
      $('table tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
        var stock = $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text();
        var cant = $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text();
        var total = $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').html (stock-(cant*dato1));
      });
    }
  }
</script>

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">                                            

 <thead>

  <tr>
    <th class="codigo" >Código</th>
    <th class="producto">Producto-Modelo</th>
    <th class="expediente" >Expediente</th>
    <th  class="stock"> Stock actual </th>
    <th class="cantidad">Cantidad</th>
    <th class="total">Stock restante</th>
  </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      ?> <tr><?php
      $codigo = $row['idcomp'];
      $producto = $row['name'] . '-' . $row['modelo'];
      $expediente = $row['expediente'];
      $stock = $row['stockactual'];
      $cantidad = $row['cantidad'];
      ?>
      <td class='codigo' ><?php echo $codigo; ?></td>
      <td class="producto" ><?php echo $producto; ?></td>
      <td class="expediente"><?php echo $expediente; ?></td>
      <td class="stock"  ><?php echo $stock; ?></td>
      <td class="cantidad"><?php echo $cantidad; ?></td>
      <td class="total" ><?php echo $Total; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
  }
  ?>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <th></th>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿podrías agregar el código HTML del problema?

Comment: El HTML de la tabla?

Comment: Claro de la tabla, para hacer pruebas y mostrar el resultado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para resolverlo puedes tener una array para colocar los que se agoten `agotados`.

Luego guardas el total en una variable antes de asignarlo a la celda, de ese modo puedes volverlo a utilizar para saber si fue negativo.

Al final si hubieron elementos con total negativo los muestras con un alert separados por comas:

```
if(agotados.length>0)
    alert('Se agotaron : '+agotados.join(', '));
```

Creo que te puede ser de ayuda cambiar el fondo de los elementos que queden negativos a rojo con una clase para saber cuales son:

```
.red{
    background: red !important;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

El código queda funcionando de la siguiente forma (puedes probar con 1000, 3000 y 10000 para ver las diferencias):

```js
function asignar() {
    var agotados=[];
    var dato1 =  document.getElementById("canti").value;
    if(dato1.trim().length == 0 ){
     alertify.alert("Atención","Por favor ingrese datos para cantidad");
     return false;
   }
   else{
    $('table tbody tr').each(function(i, tr) {
      var stock = $(tr).find('td:eq(3)').text();
      var cant = $(tr).find('td:eq(4)').text();
      var total = stock-(cant*dato1);
      $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').html (total);
      if(total<0){
        agotados.push($(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text());
        $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').addClass('red');
      }else
        $(tr).find('td:eq(5)').removeClass('red');
    });
  }
  if(agotados.length>0)
    alert('Se agotaron : '+agotados.join(', '));
}
```

```css
.red{
    background: red !important;
    color: #fff;
  }
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<input type="number" id="canti" min=1 value=1> 
<button onclick="asignar()">Asignar Cantidad</button>

<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped mb-0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="codigo" >Código</th>

      <th class="producto">Producto-Modelo</th>
      <th class="expediente" >Expediente</th>

      <th  class="stock"> Stock actual </th>
      <th class="cantidad">Cantidad</th>
      <th class="total">Stock restante</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class='codigo' >388</td>
      <td class="producto" >Azucar</td>
      <td class="expediente">XCGVRT 2018</td>
      <td class="stock"  >5470</td>
      <td class="cantidad">1</td>
      <td class="total" >-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='codigo' >389</td>
      <td class="producto" >Arroz</td>
      <td class="expediente">XCGVRT 2018</td>
      <td class="stock"  >1470</td>
      <td class="cantidad">2</td>
      <td class="total" >-</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class='codigo' >390</td>
      <td class="producto" >Pan</td>
      <td class="expediente">XCGVRT 2018</td>
      <td class="stock"  >5470</td>
      <td class="cantidad">2</td>
      <td class="total" >-</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <th></th>
   </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Impresionante...mucha gracias por tu respuesta!!!